# A tag android deve ser usada em perguntas sobre pwa?

Tags: suporte, tags, tag-específica

Os PWA são aplicações **web** progressivas, mesmo que a pergunta foque no desenvolvimento para o android, a tag deve ser utilizada?

**Observações**

- A pergunta está diretamente relacionada a parte mobile do PWA
- Foco no android porque:

  - Windows phone já morreu
  - A apple não tem muito interesse em investir na tecnologia (está muito atrás no que diz repeito a o que já é possível)
  - Os outros OS são minoria não interessante ao projeto

Comment: PWA não é nem invenção nem exclusividade de Android. A escasses de OSes mobile decentes atualmente não impede que amanhã ou depois tenhamos outras opções, e inclusive o PWA é uma maneira de qualquer OS novo já começar com aplicativos "com cara de nativo" (as "más linguas" dizem inclusive que os grandes players do mercado ficaram segurando o desenvolvimento do PWA para forçar o uso das respectivas lojas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o problema exigir que se resolva especificamente na plataforma faz sentido, se o problema não é na plataforma Android especificamente não faz sentido algum usa-la.

Claro que é ainda sim é interessante a tag [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) para o caso das pessoas que seguem os feeds de tags especificas ou até seguem tags para receber notificações:

```
 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/tag-notifications/<seu id>
```

Pois o assunto PWA pode lhes ser interessante, mas ainda sim eu vou sugerir que é melhor analisar caso a caso sobre o uso tanto de [pwa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pwa) quanto de [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), pois pode ter perguntas que na verdade não tem nada haver com PWA também (o que pode ser a maioria dos casos).

Comment: Talvez a tag `mobile` possa ser utilizada